# android: resize a child without resizing a parent

Tags: android, layout, resize, parent-child

I have a child view within a parent view. If I resize the child, the parent is also resized. Can I make parent not being resized, when I resize the child?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No? I think the premise of the view hierarchy is that a child view's bounds are contained wholly within its parent's bounds.

You could get an effect similar to the one you desire by wrapping the two views in a `FrameLayout`, allowing them to overlap as sibling views.